# Curious divisor-like sums

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello everyone

In connection with calculating the Fourier coefficients of some quasi-modular forms which I have been looking at lately, I have come across the following type of sum

$$ S_{a,b}(N) := \sum_{t=1}^{N-1} \ \ \sum_{(n,m) \in I_{N-t,t}} \frac{1}{m^a n^b} $$
where $$ I_{k,l} = \{ \ (m,n) \ \big| \ \ m|k \ , \ n| l \ , \ m>n  \}$$
Note the final condition in $I_{k,l}$ which is of course what prevents this sum from simply being a sum of products of divisor functions. My questions are

1.)  Can anybody think of a way of calculating this sum rapidly for large $N$. Perhaps by somehow expressing it as a sum of some modified divisor functions or something similar.

2.) Has series of this type occurred elsewhere in math?

Comment: What happens if you use J_{k,l} which is your I_{k,l} except with m <= n?  Can you say anything about either sum?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.12.09

Comment: I think the sum you suggest would just be my sum plus $\sigma_{a+b}(N)$, though I haven't thought it through thoroughly. Do you have any idea's in that case?

Comment: Ahh, no sorry, read your suggestion as $m\geq n $ for some reason. The sum you actually suggest would be something like $\sum_{t=1}^{N-1} sigma_a(t)\sigma_b(N-t) - S_{a,b}(N)$ right? Either way I am still interested if you have some thoughts/references in this case. 

Comment: I am not allowed to edit comments?

Comment: The only way to "edit" a comment is to delete it and re-type it. 

Comment: @torbe, you may find it easier to retype the new comment first, prior to deleting the old one.  Or use an external text editor to type the comment in first, so you'll have an easy copy of your text to modify as needed.  Perhaps the next incarnation of mathoverflow on alpha.mathoverflow.net will allow for easier editing of comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function seems related to Percy MacMahon's generalized sum-of-divisors functions. A generating function can be given as follows:

Let $A_k(q) = \sum_n a_{n,k}q^n$ where $a_{n,k}$ is given by the sum $\sum s_1 \cdots s_k$ taken over all ways of writing $k = m_1s_1 + \cdots m_ks_k$ with $0 < m_1 < \cdots < m_k$.

Specifically, $a_{2,k}$ looks similar to what you've written above: You're summing over all ways of partitioning $N$ into two numbers, and summing over the divisors of those numbers... or at least some power of their reciprocals.

I don't see exactly how to write what you've done in terms of these functions (note the condition that you have that $m > n$ is the reverse of the inequality in MacMahon's function i.e. you're summing over the product of the $m_k$ in his function instead of the $s_k$), but they're not too far off.

There is some literature on these functions; there's MacMahon's original paper "Divisors of numbers and their continuations in the theory of partitions", as well as a few papers by George Andrews more recently (one co-authored by me). These generating functions are quasi-modular forms, so it seems to be at least on a similar tack...

Comment: Very nice, even if it is not exactly the type of sums I am looking at. I trust some of the idea's used in connection with the MacMahon functions will be usefull. 

Answer (score 0):

The sum in question can be rewritten as

$\sum_{m\leq N-1}\sum_{n\leq N-1,m\leq n-1}\frac{1}{m^an^b}\sum_{t\leq N-1,t=0(\bmod m),t=N(\bmod n)}1,$

that is

$\sim (N-1)\sum_{m\leq N-1}\sum_{n\leq N-1,m\leq n-1,(m,n)|N}\frac{(m,n)}{m^{a+1}n^{b+1}}.$

Of course, there will come out a so-called "error" term, I haven't check it is really an error.

Sorry, I am not quite familar with the latex on mathoverflow.

Comment: In fact, the sum in question is bounded if $a,b>0$, in which case it is "certain constant" + $N^{-\delta},\delta>0$, maybe?

Comment: $O(N^{-\delta})$ 